# Magento: sales_order_save_after event ignore on invoice generate

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Config.xml

```
<sales_order_save_after>
<observers>
    <iula_crm_order_observer>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>iula_Crm_Model_Order_Observer</class>
        <method>sales_order_save_after_crm</method>
    </iula_crm_order_observer>
</observers>
```

Observer.php

```
public function sales_order_save_after_crm(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    // call api
}
```

Hi,

I have above code in my observer.php and i need to run this code except invoice generation. This observer is calling on invoice also, is there any way to check this.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this event is called every time the order is saved i.e order placed, status changed, invoiced, shipped etc

If you need your observer to be called excluding the invoice creation then you would need to dispatch your own event hooking in the actions to listen for.

Comment: Thank you Steven. I have created my custom event.

Comment: You are welcome Nilesh, could you vote up and mark as answer if this was what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check when was the invoice saved(updated.) If it was updated  within the last 15s then don't process your code (api call). When not then process. You can modify the 15s to any number, what suits you of course.

To Archive this, you need to modify the code something like this:

```
    <?php

public function sales_order_save_after_crm(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    try {
        $order=$observer->getOrder();

        $time = time(); //get current time
        $process = true;
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
            $date = null;
            $date = $invoice->getUpdatedAt(); //get invoice updated time
            $timedifference = $time - strtotime($date);
            if ($timedifference < 15):
                $process = false; //Stop processing when invoice was updated in the last 15s
            endif;
        }
        if ($process) {
            //call api
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
?>
```

The other solution were, to find an another event, what get called when you need it, but I assume you tried that already.